# Global variable must be contained inside of a global class

Tags: controller, javascript-remoting, global-methods

I'm building a visualforce page to be embedded in a record detail page that uses javascript remoting with a controller, and because of that I need to make the controller global for the embedded visualforce page to see it.

I've stripped out the controller to the most basic version that is triggering this error:

*** edit ***

Here's a simplified version of the actual controller, it's returning the wrapper class in this controller that requires the return type to be global.

```
global class AddressSearchController {

    // vf page can't find controller method as it needs to be global, making method global requires return type to be global
    @RemoteAction
    global static list<AddressDetail> searchAddress( String addressEntry ) {

        list<AddressDetail> addressList = new list<AddressDetail>();
        return addressList;
    }  


    // wrapper class for AddressSearch json structure
    public class AddressDetail {
        public string AddressComposite {get;set;}    

        public AddressDetail () {}
    }

}
```

The error is: "Compile Error: Global variable must be contained inside of a global class. If I remove the global tag for the addressList return variable I get "Compile Error: Return type of global method must also be global: List ". This is a clone of the actual controller so doesn't have a vf page or component referencing it, it's just failing to compile all on its own.

Can anyone tell me why this won't compile?

Comment: Try this `global List<string> addressList = new List<string>();`

Comment: Yep the second global in that row was just something I tried and forgot to delete, unfortunately not the cause of the problem. I've updated my post to remove it.

Comment: And to whoever is butthurt enough to downvote my question and post, I hope it made you feel a bit happier about yourself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the advice all. It helped me narrow the issue down to the wrapper class I was returning - the issue was I needed to make the wrapper class and constructor global as well. I had tried this previously but still had my return variable initialised as global which was causing its own compile error :-P

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
global list<string> addressList = new global list<string>();
```

Into

```
list<string> addressList = new list<string>();
```

Global variable declared at class level you are declaring a local variable. Local variable can't be global.